# Creating configurable product showing only one attribute

Tags: magento-1, administration

I have two attributes.

- Color
- Size

**admin**
Showing single attribute when creating configurable product. Next step shows multiple colors but only single size. 
**product view pages**

after creation, only colors is showing but no size attribute at product view pages
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmL2l.png

Comment: Me too have this problem. But for me after clicking the color option it moves to size attribute. Anyone having solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you assign both the attributes to the "Attribute Set" and set the option in the attribute "Use To Create Configurable Product" (the attribute must be dropdown/multiple select and global)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes both attributes are set in default

Comment: Check the answer above, I've added some screen shots

Comment: http://postimage.org/gallery/18furs8k/

SIZE Don't have "USE TO CREATE CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT" Option

Comment: Change the scope to global.